# What is the correct way for a custom Maven plugin to expose values to other plugins later in the lifecycle?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm writing a custom Maven plugin that executes an external process and receives some values from it. Those values need to be exposed to integration tests running later on in the lifecycle.

Ideally, plugins running later in the lifecycle could refer to the values published by my plugin in their `<configuration>` block using standard property interpolation: `${env.value_from_my_plugin}`.

I've also considered just writing out a `.properties` file to `/target` somewhere, but that seems like a hack.

What's the standard approach for something like this? Can I affect the "environment" during lifecycle execution and set env.* properties?

Guidance appreciated.

Comment: Simple answer: No... Why do you need something via a custom plugins which will change something in the build process? Can you elaborate more in detail what you are doing and what kind of problem you are trying to solve? In particular what kind of values this custom plugins is receiving ?

Comment: This plugin is setting up an integration testing environment in the pre-integration-test phase. The integration tests need some values generated by the plugin to function. It's a pretty straightforward use case.

Comment: To clarify, we have docker-compose bringing up a testing environment for integration tests, and each time docker-compose runs it brings up the containerized services on random ports. We can't just use standard ports because multiple integration test runs might be running on the same CI host. It would be nice to be able to set environment variables containing the ports used by the docker compose plugin so that the tests run by failsafe could pick that information up.

Comment: In the meantime we write out a properties file in pre-integration-tests with the port numbers, and pick that up in our tests. It's gross because the tests have to be aware of the build environment, but it does work.